# Video in background with controls - can't make it work

Tags: html, css

I have a wordpress site with Easywpvideo in it (which doesn't' offer support)

We want a video to play in the background, but we also want the user to be able to stop start.

We also want some content to flow over the video.

This div is created by the plugin:

```
<div id="video_background_video_0" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
```

I have tried various options with 
    .site {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1 or 100;
    }

and this brings the various content of the page into the right position, but of course the video play button isn't clickable

Are we trying to do something that can't be done? IE insert a video into the background of a page, have content on top of it BUT we able to control the video?

Comment: Could you make fiddle for the same.

Comment: Would the url help. Www.onscreencounselling.co.uk

Comment: where's the video on that page? o.O

Comment: Your link doesn't show website

Comment: sorry, i cant able to open that url.

Comment: sorry - silly me - http://www.onscreencounselling.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this.

```
       <div id="primary" class="content-area">
             <div id="video_background_video_0" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
            <iframe id="video_background_video_0_yt" style="position: absolute; top: -179px; left: 0px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="1349" height="759" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1CXFhQ33_xs?loop=0&amp;start=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.onscreencounselling.com"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
            <article id="post-576" class="post-576 page type-page status-publish hentry">
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title">homepage</h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>Here is some homepage content</p>
                    <p>And a bit more</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                <footer class="entry-meta">
                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            </article><!-- #post -->
            <div id="comments" class="comments-area">
            </div><!-- #comments -->            
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div>
```

Comment: this is interesting idea - and has started me off on a new direction of thought - perhaps I could hard code it into the site's header file... not out of the woods yet but a new line of thought... so thanks

Comment: I have used this as a basis. Now the controls appear for a couple of seconds, but don't reappears. Also you can't press them. So, still no control really! Any more thoughts please?

Comment: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/zawHg you shuld customize like this. bcoz you were set z-index:0 for video container